# пропали подскски в VS

Tags: visual-studio

Здарстуйте ,такая проблема пропали все подскаски в Visual Studio сами по себе.   работал с юнити писал функцию на C# [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пропасть сами по себе подзказки не могут. Были какие нибудь ошибки при загрузке VS?

Comment: было все нормально  при установки .В с++ все нормально все подсказки есть но в C# они пропали есть несколько подсказок но ето вопше не те к примеру Gameobject нету Input.getkey тоже и много других .

Comment: а у вас установлен компонент для работы с c#?

Comment: Да ещё вопрос: вы открываете скрипт непосредственно из папки с проектом?

Comment: ещо до того как я начал работать в юнити я установил с++ компонет и с# и работал на нем (не с играми )потом установил юнити и кое какое время все работало нормально потом написал функцию OnMouseDown и вроде после етого чтото случилось я никуда не лез  и.т.д я смотрел уроки и думаю давай повторю урок начал писать ,после етого и пропало

Comment: вы запускаете скрипт из папки проекта или через саму Unity?

Comment: через саму Unity и даже тольшто создал новый прокет таж самаю фигня

Comment: У вас настройках Unity выставлен стандартный редактор - VS?

Comment: етого незнаю сечас посмотрю

Comment: Ну что? Вы знаете где это смотреть?

Comment: все ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО за то что подсказали а я долго иска бо у меня Blend vs а я ним не пользуюсь и поиск нехотел показівать где есть простая vs пришло немного поискать

Comment: Я оформлю это как ответ, просьба засчитайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках Unity измените стандартный редактор на VS, потом просто из Unity запустите скрипт и ждите пока VS загрузится